# Matrix multiplication using hdf5

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata, matrix-multiplication, pytables

I'm trying to multiplicate 2 big matrices with memory limit using hdf5 (pytables)
but function numpy.dot seems to give me error:

> Valueerror: array is too big

I need to do matrix multiplication by myself maybe blockwise or there is some another python function similar to numpy.dot?

```
import numpy as np
import time
import tables
import cProfile
import numexpr as ne

n_row=10000
n_col=100
n_batch=10

rows = n_row
cols = n_col
batches = n_batch

atom = tables.UInt8Atom()  #?
filters = tables.Filters(complevel=9, complib='blosc') # tune parameters

fileName_a = 'C:\carray_a.h5'
shape_a = (rows*batches, cols)  # predefined size

h5f_a = tables.open_file(fileName_a, 'w')
ca_a = h5f_a.create_carray(h5f_a.root, 'carray', atom, shape_a, filters=filters)

for i in range(batches):
    data = np.random.rand(rows,cols)
    ca_a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows]= data[:]
#h5f_0.close()


rows = n_col
cols = n_row
batches = n_batch

fileName_b = 'C:\carray_b.h5'
shape_b = (rows, cols*batches)  # predefined size

h5f_b = tables.open_file(fileName_b, 'w')
ca_b = h5f_b.create_carray(h5f_b.root, 'carray', atom, shape_b, filters=filters)

#need to batch by cols
sz= rows/batches
for i in range(batches):
    data = np.random.rand(sz, cols*batches)
    ca_b[i*sz:(i+1)*sz]= data[:]
#h5f_1.close()

rows = n_batch*n_row
cols = n_batch*n_row

fileName_c = 'C:\carray_c.h5'
shape_c = (rows, cols)  # predefined size

h5f_c = tables.open_file(fileName_c, 'w')
ca_c = h5f_c.create_carray(h5f_c.root, 'carray', atom, shape_c, filters=filters)


a= h5f_a.root.carray#[:]
b= h5f_b.root.carray#[:]
c= h5f_c.root.carray

t0= time.time()
c= np.dot(a,b) #error if aray is big
print (time.time()-t0)
```

**Update:** so here is the code.It's interesting but using hdf5 it works even faster.

```
import numpy as np
import tables
import time

sz= 100 #chunk size
n_row=10000 #m
n_col=1000 #n

#for arbitrary size
A=np.random.rand(n_row,n_col)
B=np.random.rand(n_col,n_row)
# A=np.random.randint(5, size=(n_row,n_col))
# B=np.random.randint(5, size=(n_col,n_row))

#using numpy array
#C= np.zeros((n_row,n_row))

#using hdf5
fileName_C = 'CArray_C.h5'
atom = tables.Float32Atom()
shape = (A.shape[0], B.shape[1])
Nchunk = 128  # ?
chunkshape = (Nchunk, Nchunk)
chunk_multiple = 1
block_size = chunk_multiple * Nchunk
h5f_C = tables.open_file(fileName_C, 'w')
C = h5f_C.create_carray(h5f_C.root, 'CArray', atom, shape, chunkshape=chunkshape)

sz= block_size

t0= time.time()
for i in range(0, A.shape[0], sz):
    for j in range(0, B.shape[1], sz):
        for k in range(0, A.shape[1], sz):
            C[i:i+sz,j:j+sz] += np.dot(A[i:i+sz,k:k+sz],B[k:k+sz,j:j+sz])
print (time.time()-t0)

t0= time.time()
res= np.dot(A,B)
print (time.time()-t0)

print (C== res)

h5f_C.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a np.dot that work without loading into memory.  I think blocking would work pretty well.  Create a an output array (called "c" below) as pytables CArray and fill in blocks.  You should choose the chunkshape when you create it to match your blocking scheme.  Something like

```
atom = tables.Float32Atom() # you have UInt8Atom() above.  do you mean that?
shape = (a.shape[0], b.shape[1])

# you can vary block_size and chunkshape independently, but I would
# aim to have block_size an integer multiple of chunkshape
# your mileage may vary and depends on the array size and how you'll
# access it in the future.

Nchunk = 128  # ?
chunkshape = (Nchunk, Nchunk)
chunk_multiple = 1
block_size = chunk_multiple * Nchunk
c = h5f.create_carray(h5.root, 'c', atom, shape, chunkshape=chunkshape)

for i_start in range(0, a.shape[0], block_size):
    for j_start in range(0, b.shape[1], block_size):
        for k_start in range(0, a.shape[1], block_size):
            c[i_start:i_start+block_size, j_start:j_start + block_size] += \ 
                    np.dot(a[i_start:i_start + block_size, k_start:k_start + block_size],
                           b[k_start:k_start + block_size, j_start:j_start + block_size]
```

Comment: chunksize must be dependent on some settings of hdf5 file?

Comment: I meant chunkshape.  It's a parameter you can pass when creating hdf5 arrays.  It's "The shape of the data chunk to be read or written in a single HDF5 I/O operation"

Comment: thanks it works,see update, can you explain why it works faster than numpy.dot?

Comment: On my 2G RAM machine, the `hdf5` block version is slower, 210sec v 70sec (for single np.dot call).  `C` which is `(10000,10000)` takes 760 Mb of memory, so memory swapping is a significant part of np.dot time.

Comment: mrgloom.  hdf5 stores matrices in chunks on disk.  You want to go to disk as little as possible, so you want to minimize the number of times you retrieve a chunk.  Calling numpy.dot will probably end up pulling more chunks from disk than necessary because the underlying BLAS routine is optimized based on the processor cache size, not hdf5s chunk size.  Doing the blocking explicitly ensures you only go to disk when needed.  It's like another level of cache (except on disk).  @hpaulj are you sure that matrix is big enough to see an effect?