# Python - parallelize a python loop for 2D masked array?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, parallel-processing, mask

Probably a commonplace question, but how can I parallelize this loop in Python?

```
for i in range(0,Nx.shape[2]):
  for j in range(0,Nx.shape[2]):
    NI=Nx[:,:,i]; NJ=Nx[:,:,j]
    Ku[i,j] = (NI[mask!=True]*NJ[mask!=True]).sum()
```

So my question: what's the easiest way to parallelize this code?

```
         ---------- EDIT LATER------------------
```

An example of data

```
import random
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy import unravel_index    

#my input
Nx = np.random.rand(5,5,5)  

#mask creation
mask_positions = zip(*np.where((Nx[:,:,0] < 0.4)))
mask_array_positions = np.asarray(mask_positions)
i, j = mask_array_positions.T
mask = np.zeros(Nx[:,:,0].shape, bool)
mask[i,j] = True
```

And i want to calculate Ku by parallelizing. My aim is to use the Ku array to solve a linear problem so i have to put the mask values apart (represent near the half of my array)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) is a good starting place.

Comment: By the way, outside of implementing @hpaulj's excellent answer, you might want to consider that your mask, which you fabricate in 5 lines is equivalent to just writing `mask = Nx[:,:,0] < 0.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to 'vectorize', to use `numpy` terminology, not parallelize in the multiprocess way.

Your calculation is essentially a dot (matrix) product.  Apply the `mask` once to the whole array to get a 2d array, `NIJ`.  Its shape will be `(N,5)`, where `N` is the number of `True` values in `~mask`.  Then it's just a `(5,N)` array 'dotted' with a `(N,5)` - ie. sum over the `N` dimension, leaving you with a `(5,5)` array.

```
NIJ = Nx[~mask,:]
Ku = np.dot(NIJ.T,NIJ)
```

In quick tests it matches the `Ku` produced by your double loop.  Depending on the underlying library used for `np.dot` there might be some multicore calculation, but that's usually not a priority issue for `numpy` users.

---

Applying the large boolean `mask` is the most time consuming part of these calculations - both the vectorized and iterative versions.

For a `mask` with 400,000 True values, compare these 2 indexing times:

```
In [195]: timeit (NI[:400,:1000],NJ[:400,:1000])
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.87 us per loop
In [196]: timeit (NI[mask],NJ[mask])
10 loops, best of 3: 98.8 ms per loop
```

Selecting the same number of items with basic (slice) indexing is several orders of magnitude faster than advanced indexing with the `mask`.

Substituting `np.dot(NI[mask],NJ[mask])` for `(NI[mask]*NJ[mask]).sum()` only saves a few ms.

Comment: I have to do this on great arrays and a great number of time and then i solve a system with these arrays with 'np.linalg.solve' I would like to accelerate it...

Comment: @user3601754 did you *try* this code? It's fast. Perform some timing comparisons if you need convincing. I know the history of your questions and you should definitely consider this solution before attempting to do multiprocessing.

Comment: 13.237869 secondes for my case and i m waiting the results since 2mins for this code

Comment: What size of arrays are you working with?  And which takes more time, applying the mask or doing the `dot`?  With large enough ones there might be a trade off between memory use and vectorization.

Comment: My Nx array has a shape : (1400, 1528, 20) and i have to repeat the calculation a lot of time! it seems to be the mask step

Comment: With that shape your iterative approach might well be faster.  Making an array of that size and applying a mask produces an error (on my old linux machine): `ValueError: dimensions too large in fancy indexing`.  Your `Ku` is only `(20,20)`, small compared to the other arrays.

Comment: I'd challenge that notion. I've done [the timings](http://pastebin.com/HdFvbzMG) on my raspberry pi (rev 2, model B), which has 512MB RAM & a single-core CPU of 700MHz: it's not because you had a ValueError that vectorization might be slower than the double for-loop, that depends entirely on the dataset and RAM. I'm hoping the OP would shed some light on how he does the timing tests, because I have the feeling they are not as we expect. @user3601754 can you explain *how* you time the code and what the output is when you run the code from the pastebin?

Comment: I changed my `mask` so it only had 400,000 True values, and calculated `Ku` with my `dot` method - 600ms per loop.

Comment: For the same data, the OP loop method took 85 sec.

Comment: I got the time with :  tic=time.clock()  before the code and  toc=time.clock() after the code and so :  print 'Temps=', toc-tic. I m using this Ku array to solve a linear system (but that step is very fast)

Comment: So to go back to my first question...can we parallelize this loop in order to be faster?

Comment: @user3601754 I see you've finally accepted one of the answers. I'm assuming that means you are getting time improvements by running this code? Care to enlighten us why the timings you mentioned (your code: 13s vs vectorized-dot: 291s) were not at all what we expected?

Comment: I added some timings to show that indexing with `mask` is the most time consuming part of these calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend @hpaulj's excellent answer (great analysis of the problem too by the way) for large matrices.

The operation

```
Ku = np.dot(NIJ.T,NIJ)
```

can be replaced by

```
Ku = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', NIJ, NIJ)
```

It should also be noted that `np.dot` [could fall back to slower routines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839985/2476444) if numpy was not compiled to use BLAS.

For a test matrix `NIJ` of shape `(1250711, 50)`, I got `54.9 s` with the `dot` method, while the `einsum` does it in `1.67 s`. On my system, numpy is compiled with BLAS support.

**Remark**: *`np.einsum` does not always outperform `np.dot`*, a situation that became apparent on my system when you would compare any of the following

```
Nx = np.random.rand(1400,1528,20).astype(np.float16)
Nx = np.random.rand(1400,1528,20).astype(np.float32)
```

(or even a dtype of `np.float64`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! if i use your code, i got 263.650027 sec :) For the moment, my code is the better (in my case)!

Comment: @user3601754, you should consider hpaulj's comment: without more information about the size of the arrays you're working on (and possible the size of the RAM), it's hard to improve on this algorithm even more. Just FYI, using hpaulj's algorithm (without the `einsum`), on a matrix of `Nx = np.random.rand(500,5000,50)`, I saw a threefold speed improvement compared to your method. But such speed gains depend a lot on the dimensions of the arrays involved (is the last axis the biggest one?)

Comment: Ok! my shape is (1400, 1528, 20)

Comment: and my type is float64